# Geocode as soon as PostGIS table is updated

Tags: python, postgis

I am trying to create a map such that as soon as I enter an address into PostGIS table, it'll automatically be geocoded (and published in geoserver). The only way I could think of doing this was using plpythonu, but plpythonu is not working properly. Any ideas on how to do this, preferably not using anythong other that sql or python and without using plpythonu?

EDIT: I need to figure out something that does not involve PL/Python.

Comment: A trigger? You haven't given very much information about how you are doing the geocoding.

Comment: I was going to create a function something like  [here](http://movingspatial.blogspot.com/2011/05/google-geocoder-in-postgis-with-reverse.html "Title") and then have a trigger that would run the function every time new data was inserted. Its a bit moot though, because I can't import geopy, and create the function in the first place.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I don't know how I would do the geocoding. The module I have mostly been using is geopy, but I'm not particularly tied to geopy. I'm a beginner at programming, but by the look of it I don't think psycopg2 or geoalchemy would be of much use, and maybe something using a restful API might help, but I have no idea how REST actually works.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. I would suggest you go and try a few tutorials and come back if you into difficulties.

Comment: Tutorials of what? That's mostly what I'd like to figure out. I don't have too much time to create this map, and I don't want to spend a lot of time teaching myself something with REST or javascript or something, and figure out it doesn't do what I need it to.

Answer (score 1):

Make a PL/Python function for geocoding (using `geopy`), and use it in a database trigger.

See answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26598462/327026).

Comment: Is there any way that does not involve using PL/Python. I figured out how to do it using PL/Python on my own, but PL/Python refuses to work properly on my computer. I was wondering if there was an alternative way that did not involve PL/Python

Comment: There are dozens of other languages (e.g. PL/Perl) but are less used and supported. I would use PL/Python because it works, if used correctly.